# Ember.js widgets/components?

Tags: widget, ember.js

Ember.js is a well written micro architecture framework but how does it address the problem of using/configuring commonly needed widgets? (e.g a DataGrid or calendar flyout)

What approach are you using to integrate widgets with Ember.js ? Cherrypick from JQueryUI/roll your own then wrap them in a View ? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read http://yehudakatz.com/2011/06/11/using-sproutcore-2-0-with-jquery-ui/. There are some API changes you need to account for, but the general approach is valid.